# How to filter a sublist of items

Tags: c#, .net, linq, filter, sublist

I want a `List<Container>` where `Container.Active == true` and give me only `containerObject.Items > 2`.  How can I filter the sublist in this way?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Container
    {
        public List<int> Items { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }

        public Container(bool active, params int[] items)
        {
            Items = items.ToList();
            Active = active;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var containers = new List<Container> {new Container(true,1, 2, 3), new Container(false, 1,2,3,4,5,6), new Container(true,1,2,5,6,7,8,9,10)};
            var result = containers.Where(c => c.Active);

            foreach (var container in result)
            {
                foreach (var item in container.Items)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item);//I should not print any values less than two here
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I should not print any values less than two where noted.

Comment: Do you mean the Container's length should be > 2?

Comment: I mean each `int` in `Items` should be > 2.  Anything less than 2 should be removed.

Comment: I thought at first that you meant you wanted a sublist starting from index 2, since that's what you said in the title. If that were the case, you would use `containers.Skip(2).Where(c => c.Active)`.

Comment: this question is a classic case of the Fastest Gun in the West problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result = from container in containers.Where(c => c.Active)
             from item in container.Items
             where item > 2
             select container;
```

In standard form:

```
var standard_result = containers
    .Where(container => container.Active && container.Items.All(i => i > 2))
    .SelectMany(con => con.Items);
```

Comment: +1 This is very much what I had in mind.  It would be nice to see this in standard method form.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey - pls do chk the standard form !

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/40318759/linqpad1.png, https://dl.dropbox.com/u/40318759/linqpad2.png. Also, your standart form is wrong - check this article http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work.aspx.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
var result = containers.Where(c => c.Active && c.Items.Count() > 2);
```

Comment: @Downvoter - care to comment? I have edited my post to accommodate the OP's updated answer.

Comment: This will not work even with your edit. The OP wants the inner list to not contain items less than 2. This will return the container with 0,1 still

Answer (score 2):

You will have to create a new `Container`. Unless you want to alter the existing one (I will add that code if that is what you need)

```
var result = containers.Where(c => c.Active)
    .Select(c=>new Container(c.Active, c.Select(i=>i>2).ToArray()))
    .Select(c=>c.Items.Count > 0);
```

The last line makes sure to not return if all items are filtered out.

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect what I believe you are looking for

Answer (score 2):

From your feedback, I presume that you're looking for a query like this:

```
var result = containers
    .Where(c => c.Active)
    .Select(c => new Container(c.Active, c.Items.Where( i => i>2).ToArray()));
```

it makes copies of the containers, except it filters out the items which are not greater than 2

Comment: The latter version works.  The first one produced no results.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey none of the containers actually satisfy the first version, because they all contain at least 1 item that is less than `2`  I presume that the second version was more or less what you were looking for?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't really need to do it in a single query:

```
var result = containers.Where(c => c.Active).ToList();
result.ForEach(c => c.Items.RemoveAll(i => i <= 2));
```